# How can I qfold the currently applied patches?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I have two Mercurial patches applied with MQ. I would like to fold them into one, but `qfold` requires the patches to be un-applied. Why? And how can I fold them without explicitly popping?

Answer (score 1):

The patch to be folded needs to be un-applied, in order to be folded onto an applied (current) patch.

```
hg qfold [-e] [-k] [-m TEXT] [-l FILE] PATCH...

fold the named patches into the current patch

    Patches must not yet be applied. Each patch will be successively applied
    to the current patch in the order given. If all the patches apply
    successfully, the current patch will be refreshed with the new cumulative
    patch, and the folded patches will be deleted.
```

With only 2 patches, you only need to un-apply the last patch to fold it on the `qbase` patch.